# How to add a custom tag in xml using xmlbuilder package in node javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, sax, xml-builder

I am having a case where I want to add this tag in my xml just below the prolog something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?AXOXMLMAP FILE=gnvouchr LIBRARY=. ;VOLUME=xmlmap?>
```

I am able to add the first line , but not getting how do I add the second line. If I use **create** it adds the closing tag as well. I just want this one single tag with the properties I have mentioned.

I am using xmlbuilder npm package. If there is any other npm package that can serve this purpose, that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIth some research I found out that the line after prolog which I have mentioned below is preprocessing information ( instructions ). To add instructions we can either use :
`instructionBefore/instructionAfter` or `instruction` for adding pre-processing information using xmlbuilder npm package.

Eg :

```
let root = xmlbuilder.create('foo', {
version : '1.0' }).instruction('bar', 'random_key = "random_value"');
root.end({'pretty': true});

//Output :
<?xml version="1.0">
<?bar random_key = "random_value">
<foo>
..
</foo>
```